# BindingList when load items

Tags: c#, bindinglist

I have this on **framework v3.5 PRJ**

```
public BindingList<BackupItem> bb = new BindingList<BackupItem>();
```

when

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    checkedListBox1.DataSource = bb;

    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "backupName";
}
```

I have implement add/edit/delete 'touching' only the **BindingList** all working as expected, at the end going to save/load the **BindingList** contents.

-Save done -Load done

hmm when loading the records not appear at **checkedListBox1** !!

To display the records, I have to re init **checkedListBox1** with

```
private void toolStripJSONLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tmp = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\path.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

    JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    bb = oSerializer.Deserialize<BindingList<BackupItem>>(tmp);

    checkedListBox1.DataSource = null;

    checkedListBox1.DataSource = bb;

    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "backupName";
}
```

anyone knows anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement:

```
bb = oSerializer.Deserialize<BindingList<BackupItem>>(tmp);
```

is creating a whole new object, pointing to a different memory location from where `checkedListBox1.DataSource` is pointing to.

What you need to do is modify the content of the `bb` variable. First clear the content then add the new items. Something like this:

```
private void toolStripJSONLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tmp = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\path.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

    JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var tmpObj = oSerializer.Deserialize<List<BackupItem>>(tmp);
    bb.Clear();
    tmpObj.ForEach(o => bb.Add(o));
}
```